# why returns does not match with string?

Tags: python-3.x, function

my `Setting.txt`: 
`mode = spam`

```
def read_setting():
    try :
        setting = open("Setting.txt","r")
        mode = setting.readline().split(" ")[2]
        print("Mode: "+mode)
        return str(mode)
    except:
        print("There is/are error in Setting.txt\nPlease check if you have the file / correct the file formatting")
        exit()
```

The func returns `spam`(confirmed this by manual debugging and its returns what i want) , 
But at my main program ,

```
def intro():
    print("This is just a print\n")

def main():
    intro()
    moded = read_setting()
    if moded == "spam":
        timer()
    elif moded == "paste":
        paste()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the func `timer()` does not run
it turns out, when i do `print(moded=="spam")` , it returns `False`
What am i wrong here?
**My Python:**

> Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)
> [GCC 9.3.0] on linux

Comment: Hint: what does `print(ascii(moded))` show?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your code? but in my case `print(moded=="spam")` prints True

Comment: @MarkTolonen Oh dude , i forgot bout that , and solved it...it works now

Comment: most probably there is something wrong with your txt file please save it again and carefully check if there are any extra spaces or newlines

Comment: @AmirulAkmal please give a clarification of how you solved it if its fit for the community as an answer or just delete the question is it was some typo

Answer (score 0):

You can see the differences if you do `print(ascii(moded))` 
 It will gives an output of `spam\n`
that's why `spam\n == spam` returns `False`
do a `moded = moded.rstrip("\n")` and that'll solved the problem